# Checking for nill equality in custom == operator

Tags: ios, swift, oop, null, operator-overloading

So I have a custom operator for equality on a class, i want to return true if they are both nil however my operator gets called when i ask if left or right == nil. Is there another or better way to do this?

```
public func == (left: classXYZ?, right: classXYZ?) -> Bool {
    if left == nil && right == nil {
        return true
    }
    if left != nil && right != nil {
        return left!.uniquID == right!.uniquID
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Btw, why don't you just do : `return left?.uniquID == right?.uniquID`? This will return true If both of them is nil.

Comment: Use the nil check build into another class, smart. That deff works. However if i could not do that how would i do a nil check with out calling my own operator

Comment: Which version of Swift are you using?

Comment: Xcode 7.2 so swift 2.2 however i am not aposed to using something introduced in swift 3.0

Comment: @CWineland: I was just trying to reproduce your scenario

Comment: @appzYourLife yeah so the first condition of the if, left == nil, literaly calls the function again haha

Comment: Why not use ozgur's suggestion? 

public func == (left: classXYZ?, right: classXYZ?) -> Bool { return left?.uniquID == right?.uniquID  }

Comment: @CWineland: How is your class defined? Is it conform to `Equatable`?

Comment: I did and it works, however that is relying on the nil check of that other class (happens to be an Int), if i did not have that how could i solve this problem?

Comment: @appzYourLife boom there it is, i knew there had to be something like that, if you write that up as the answer ill accept it. That totaly works. Good catch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the code to make your class `Equatable`

```
class ClassXYZ: Equatable {
    let uniqueID: String

    init(uniqueID: String) {
        self.uniqueID = uniqueID
    }
}

func ==(left: ClassXYZ, right: ClassXYZ) -> Bool {
    return left.uniqueID == right.uniqueID
}
```

You don't need (and you can't) to explicitly specify that `nil == nil` is `true`, it is already built into Swift, look

```
let a: ClassXYZ? = nil
let b: ClassXYZ? = nil

print(a == b) // true
```